# NaT error when adding column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a dataframe of dates in python. I am using dates as the index :

```
aDates.head(5)
Out[114]: 
0   2009-12-31
1   2010-01-01
2   2010-01-04
3   2010-01-05
4   2010-01-06
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I then create an empty dataframe:

```
dfAll_dates = pd.DataFrame(index = aDates)
```

I got then a function that creates a pandas Series of dates that I am trying to add as a column, but so that you can reproduce easily, let's assume we add the same serie that we used for the index :

```
dfAll_dates['my_added_column'] = aDates
```

But this results in :

```
dfAll_dates.head(5)

Out[120]: 
           my_added_column
Date                      
2009-12-31             NaT
2010-01-01             NaT
2010-01-04             NaT
2010-01-05             NaT
2010-01-06             NaT
```

I tried to convert my dates to timestamp using .totimestamp on aDates, but this did not solve the problem (I then have a "bound method Series.to_timestamp of 0") , and as there is no types in the definition I do not see why I would have to convert anyway.

Could you please help on this ?

Comment: What is your expected output?  You indexes are not lining up.  You create an index of dates then you assign a series of Dates, with an index of integers starting at 0.  Therefore, you dataframe with index of dates returns NaT.  Your series doesn't line up with your index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is problem there are different `indexes` in `Series` and `DataFrame`, so data no align and get `NaN`s:

One possible solution is convert values of `aDates` to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html):

```
dfAll_dates = pd.DataFrame(index = aDates)
dfAll_dates['my_added_column'] = aDates.values
print (dfAll_dates)
           my_added_column
Date                      
2009-12-31      2009-12-31
2010-01-01      2010-01-01
2010-01-04      2010-01-04
2010-01-05      2010-01-05
2010-01-06      2010-01-06
```

Or use [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), also is necessary rename column:

```
d = {'Date':'my_added_column'}
df = aDates.to_frame().set_index('Date', drop=False).rename(columns=d)
print (df)
           my_added_column
Date                      
2009-12-31      2009-12-31
2010-01-01      2010-01-01
2010-01-04      2010-01-04
2010-01-05      2010-01-05
2010-01-06      2010-01-06
```

Or use `DataFrame` constructor with `dict` for new column:

```
dfAll_dates = pd.DataFrame({'my_added_column':aDates.values}, index = aDates)
print (dfAll_dates)
           my_added_column
Date                      
2009-12-31      2009-12-31
2010-01-01      2010-01-01
2010-01-04      2010-01-04
2010-01-05      2010-01-05
2010-01-06      2010-01-06
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the `pd.Index.to_series` method that creates a series where the values take on what is in the index and the index remains the same.

```
dfAll_dates['my_added_column'] = dfAll_dates.index.to_series()
```

That takes care of the index alignment.  However, you didn't even need to do that.  As @jezrael showed, if we eliminate passing a series object and only pass an array, `pandas` won't attempt to align an index that isn't there.  We can accomplish the same thing by referring directly to the index

```
dfAll_dates['my_added_column'] = dfAll_dates.index
```

In either case

```
dfAll_dates

           my_added_column
2009-12-31      2009-12-31
2010-01-01      2010-01-01
2010-01-04      2010-01-04
2010-01-05      2010-01-05
2010-01-06      2010-01-06
```

In both of these scenarios, we are no longer required to track `aDates` and only need to refer to objects already present in `dfAll_dates`.